# How do you set a session variable/cookie in Django in the html?

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering how you can set a session variable/cookie in Django inside the html. Specifically, I'm trying to store a location after a user logs in and accepts gps tracking. I later want to retrieve the location so that I can pass it around in various views.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you dont save things in session **inside the html.** session data will be saved into mostly (also possible: db, memcached, network driver etc) user harddrive, mostly into `tmp` folder. this is just for your information.

regarding your plan:

you can save user gps data into session and get from session in this way: (not tested!)

```
def post_comment(request, new_comment):
   user_gps = request.session.get('user_gps_%s' % request.user.username, None)
   if user_gps: 
       # do something with user gps
       return ... 
   user_gps = request.POST.get('user_gps_post_data')
   request.session['user_gps_%s' % request.user.username] = user_gps
   return ...
```